# node async module: combine parallel with retry

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js, node-async

Here's a simple example of the use of [`async.parallel`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel):

```
var fakeTimer = 0;
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        if (fakeTimer < 2) {
            callback(new Error('too soon!'), null);
            fakeTimer++;
        } else {
            callback(null, 'I am one');
        }
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'I am two');
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failed!');
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

When this runs, of course it always ends in failure.  What I'd like to do is keep retrying until `fakeTimer` has become large enough that the `one` function succeeds.

So either the whole `async.parallel` could be retried e.g. 5 times, or just the `one` function.  I know that there is the [`async.retry`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#retry) feature, but I just can't get my head around how to combine that with `async.parallel` to achieve what I want.

I think ideally the whole `async.parallel` should be retried, so that it works if the error happens in any of the parallel branches, but it would be great to see an example of an overall retry and a per-branch retry.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
var fakeTimer = 0;

var parallelFunctions = {
    one: function(callback) {
        if (fakeTimer < 2) {
            callback(new Error('too soon!'), null);
            fakeTimer++;
        } else {
            callback(null, 'I am one');
        }
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'I am two');
    }
};

var doThemInParallel = function(callback) {
    async.parallel(parallelFunctions, function(err, results) {
        callback(err, results);
    });
};

var retries = 2; // must be > 2 to succeed
async.retry(retries, doThemInParallel, function(err, results) {
    console.log(err, results);
});
```